# Flutter how to filter a list?

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to build a product page with a datatable with the product´s aplicattions.
I want to filter using the product id, in this case "note.id". I don´tt know how and where to filter data, I can only show the full list. Any ideias?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:catalogo/entities/note.dart';
import 'package:snapshot_carousel/snapshot_carousel.dart';

class ProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Note note;

  ProductScreen(this.note);

  @override
  _ProductScreenState createState() => _ProductScreenState(note);
}

class _ProductScreenState extends State<ProductScreen> {
  final Note note;

  List<Aplicacao> _aplicacoes = List<Aplicacao>();
  List<Note> _aplicacoesDisplay = List<Note>();

  _ProductScreenState(this.note);

  Future<List<Aplicacao>> fetchNotes() async {
    var data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('assets/json/produtos.json');
    var body = json.decode(data);
    var aplicacoes = List<Aplicacao>();
    for (var appliJson in body) {
      aplicacoes.add(Aplicacao.fromJson(appliJson));
    }
    return aplicacoes;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchNotes().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _aplicacoes.addAll(value);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Color primaryColor =
        Theme.of(context).primaryColor; // PEGA COR PRIMARIA DO TEMA

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(note.id),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                SnapShotCarousel.snapShotCarousel([
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/${note.imagem}",
                    //height: 300.0,
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/${note.id}_1.png",
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/${note.id}_2.png",
                  ),
                ],
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    featureImageHeight: 400,
                    placeholderImageHeight: 60,
                    selectedImageBorderColor: Colors.green,
                    unselectedImageBorderColor: Colors.grey),
                Text(
                  note.id,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 3,
                ),
                DataTable(
                  headingTextStyle: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .overline
                      .copyWith(fontSize: 12.0),
                  showCheckboxColumn: false,
                  dataRowHeight: 54.0,
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Segmento')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Montadora')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Veículo')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Motor')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Obs.')),
                  ],
                  //rows: []
                  rows: _aplicacoes
                      .map((data) => DataRow(
                              cells: [
                                DataCell(Text(data.segmento)),
                                DataCell(Text(data.montadora)),
                                DataCell(Text(data.veiculo)),
                                DataCell(Text(data.motor)),
                                DataCell(Text(data.obs)),
                              ]))
                      .toList(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below you can see the product page and the full aplicattions list.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
final _filteredList = _aplicacoes.where((product) => product.id == 'productID').toList();
```

This will provide you the list of products having product id = 'productID'.